# Left part of Dash is hidden off-screen

Tags: multiple-monitors, unity-dash

After getting new monitors and following instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67495/getting-dual-monitors-to-work-on-11-10), the markers to the left of icons in Dash (the ones which show open windows) are nearly completely off-screen. How can I fix this?

`xorg.conf`:

```
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 280.13  (buildd@yellow)  Fri Aug  5 12:31:28 UTC 2011


Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"

    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Acer A221HQL"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 83.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 75.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GT 520"
EndSection

Section "Screen"

# Removed Option "TwinViewXineramaInfoOrder" "CRT-1"
# Removed Option "metamodes" "DFP: nvidia-auto-select +0+0, CRT: nvidia-auto-select +1280+0"
# Removed Option "TwinViewXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-0"
# Removed Option "metamodes" "CRT: nvidia-auto-select +1920+0, DFP: nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "TwinView" "1"
    Option         "TwinViewXineramaInfoOrder" "CRT-1"
    Option         "metamodes" "CRT: nvidia-auto-select +0+0, DFP: nvidia-auto-select +1920+0"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```